# Android copy database directory issue?

Tags: android

I have a application which need to access assets folder database to get data when application start, so I doing some copy data from assets action, but in last release, user say that cannot open the application, so some user can.

May I know, if I need to copy a database from assets folder to user device, which database directory path should I use to store the copied database? or missing some important thing in my code?

as now, I just doing this on device:

createDirectory:

```
public boolean createDirectory() {  
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
    {
        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+GlobalConfig.CONFIG_DATA_DIR;
        if( isNeedDL( rootPath )) {
            File myDir = new File(rootPath);
            return myDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and database directory, which GlobalConfig.CONFIG_DATA_DIR = "/data/"

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+GlobalConfig.CONFIG_DATA_DIR;
```

and in SQLiteOpenHelper class: check if database exited, do copy action.

```
private NOLDatabaseHelper(Context context, String path) {
    super(context, path + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}   

public void createDatabase() {

    if(!isDatabaseExited()) {
        Log.v(GlobalConfig.TAG, "NO database");
        getReadableDatabase();
        copyDataBaseFromAsset();
    } else {
        Log.v(GlobalConfig.TAG, "Has database");
    }
}

public static boolean isDatabaseExited() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( DB_PATH + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();

        Log.v(GlobalConfig.TAG,"check? "+DB_PATH + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME+" checkDB:"+checkDB);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {}

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Thanks!

Here is copy function:

```
// to fix database is locked issue
private synchronized void copyDataBaseFromAsset() 
{
    int length                  = -1;
    byte[] buffer               = new byte[1024];
    AssetManager am             = context.getAssets();

    try 
    {
        InputStream assetsDB    = am.open(DB_NAME_INDBNAME);
        String outFileName      = DB_PATH + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME;
        OutputStream dbOut      = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        while ((length = assetsDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        dbOut.flush();
        dbOut.close();
        assetsDB.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e( GlobalConfig.TAG, "copyDataBaseFromAsset error, is say: "+e.toString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the method copyDataBaseFromAsset on post, big thanks~

Answer (score 0):

below is a working code for copying database from assets folder to data directory:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// varaible declaration
public static String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
private static String DB_NAME = "DMDatabase.sqlite";//file name in assets
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase;
private final Context myContext;
private String DatabasePath;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DatabasePath = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName()
            + "/databases/";
}

/**
 * Method to create the database inside application
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    try {

        // check if the database exists
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            // database is not present copy databse
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabse();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                // String ex = e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DatabasePath + DB_NAME);
            if (file.exists()) {
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DatabasePath
                        + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d("DB Exception", "");
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by tranfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDatabse() throws IOException {
    try {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DatabasePath + DB_NAME;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 2];
        int length;

        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            try {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    createDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Other Methods to insert,delete, update,select in Database
 */

}
```

I hope will be helpful for you.

> **But it is not recommended process to copy database from assets from data directory. Once the database on created, `onCreate` method will be called in which you should use queries to create tables and insert default data into database.**