# Android database path change issue

Tags: android

I have a production application need to access database , my application using follow path:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+dbname
```

The question is some using is work but some user not work, I know that is because of  the database path,

- May I know is the path make something wrong ?
- Which path setting should I use to make all device work ?

Ps: database will copy to that path directory

Big Thanks

Comment: Please give us more info, what is not working? Also it could be heplful if you share more of your code.

Comment: Hello, here is my org question: Android copy database directory issue? - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29812331/924840 , thanks for your help